# Simple mongoose populate doesn't seem to be working

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose

I have the following 2 schema's

question.js

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
    var Schema = mongoose.Schema;

    var questionsSchema = new Schema({
        nr: Number,
        points: Number,
        description: String,
        isActive: {type: Boolean, required: true, default: true}
    });

    module.exports = mongoose.model('Question', questionsSchema);
```

round.js

```
 var mongoose = require('mongoose');

var Schema = mongoose.Schema;


var roundSchema = new Schema({
    name: String,
    index: Number,
    questions: {type: [Schema.Types.ObjectId], ref: 'Question'},
    createdOn: {type: Date, required: true, default: Date.now()},
    isActive: {type: Boolean, required: true, default: true}
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('Round', roundSchema);
```

There is some data that gets filled correctly, however when I try even the most simple query, it won't even work:

```
var Round = require('../model/round.server.model.js');

function findAll(req, res) {
        Round.find().populate('questions').exec(function (err, results) {
            if (err) {
                console.log("An error occured when receiving all rounds!", err);
                return res.sendStatus(404);
            }
            console.log(results);
            return res.send(results);
        });
    }
```

All rounds are retrieved, but the question arrays are empty, even the _id's themselves disappeared

Comment: Do you have `_id` in your `Questions` schema and just left it out in your code snippet by accident?  Mongoose won't pull fields not in the schema, so if it's really not there that could be why.

Comment: I don't, but the _id is filled in automatically if you don't specify it. On initialization I first save all questions and then add the questionIds (after they're saved) to the relevant rounds

Comment: That's right it's created by MongoDB but I think Mongoose only pulls the fields which are defined in the schema, easy enough to try adding it and see if populate then works, esp. since database already has them

Comment: All right I will give it a try then

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it's because you initialize in the wrong way your population. I understand you want an array of questions in each of your round. Your error seems to be here.

```
 questions: {type: [Schema.Types.ObjectId], ref: 'Question'}
```

You should do as following in order to make it work:

```
 questions: [{type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Question'}]
```

Because actually, you're making an array of `type` and this doesn't mean anything.

Comment: That was it! Thanks you've saved me a big headache!